# How can I fit a GMM to a 1D Gaussian plot with sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I realize there are several articles that demonstrate how to fit a GMM to a 1D Gaussian with sklearn ([[1]](http://www.astroml.org/book_figures/chapter4/fig_GMM_1D.html) and [[2]](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4717), to name a few). However, in all of those cases, the data is present as single points where the distribution is Gaussian. In my case, I'm essentially have a frequency table (I'm working with spectroscopic data), where the distribution is Gaussian, but the individual points are unknown.

My distribution (i.e., the data I'm trying to fit) looks like this: [1D Gaussian Peak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a7LU.png)

I'd like to use GMM to deconvolve the 2 initial Gaussian distributions that make up this peak.

So far, I've tried the following (assume my data is a 200x2 array, with position in one column and AFU on the second) :

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import mixture
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def gengmm(nc=4, n_iter = 2):
  g = mixture.GMM(n_components=nc)  # number of components
  g.init_params = ""  # No initialization
  g.n_iter = n_iter   # iteration of EM method
  return g
```

I tried to see if I could fit this peak to just a single Gaussian:

```
g = gengmm(1, 100) 
g.fit(data)
```

However, the mean and covariance I get don't define my data particularly well (notably, the mean for that Gaussian distribution is 127.5, which is not what is recovered with a 1 component GMM).

Is there an easier way to do this? (I realize I can just use a least-squares fit to recover the initial Gaussian, but again, I'm trying to ultimately use this to determine the two underlying Gaussians distributions that make up the final one.)

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, you're trying to fit the PDF of the distribution, not a sample of points drawn from that distribution, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's basically correct. (The real answer is a bit more nuanced because of the experiment I'm running, but you can model it as a PDF.)